# Formula for text before and after space in a string

Tags: string, excel-formula, substitution

I'm attempting to create usernames based off of a given persons first and last name. Generally, we use the first initial and last name for a username. However, now many of our users have 2 last names and sometimes include a hyphen. I am trying to create a code that gives me the first initial, the first letter of the FIRST last name and then the last name.

For example --

Amy Smith-Jones ==
asjones

This is what I am currently using, but, of course, it would yield "asmithjones".

```
=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")," ",""))
```

I've tried some variations of this, but with no luck.

```
=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)&LEFT(A2,1)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")," ",""))
```

**Is there a way to generate both the first letter of the first string and the full text of the 2nd string?**

**EDIT**

I came up with something, but now I face another challenge

```
=IFERROR(LOWER(LEFT(D2,1)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(F2,LEN(F2)-FIND(" ",F2&" ")),"-","")," ","")),LOWER(LEFT(D2,1)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F2,"-","")," ","")))
```

Some users have 1 last name so this applies if the formula comes across those. But I have some who have a hyphen instead of a space. The SUSTITUTE function accounts for both, but **how can I make the FIND function do the same?**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)&MID(A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1),1)&RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-(SEARCH(" ",(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," ")),(SEARCH(" ",A1)+1)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, I'll assume first names are in column D and last names are in column F:

```
=LOWER(LEFT(D2) & IFERROR(LEFT(F2)&MID(F2,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(F2," ","-"))+1,99), F2))
```

`SUBSTITUTE` changes spaces to hyphens in the last name, so `FIND` can look for hyphens only.

`IFERROR` fails if a hyphen is not found (after substitution), in which case the entire last name is returned.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: This is fabulous! Thanks so much! Looks like mine got a bit wacky.